# Dynamically call JavaScript function with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom-events

How can I call this function dynamically? How can I pass arguments dynamically inside braces of this dynamic call?

```
function a(b,c,d){
}

var functionName = 'a';
window [functionName]();
```

Comment: You mean, `window[function](arg1,arg2,arg3)`?

Comment: What's wrong with `window[functionName](1,2,3);`?

Comment: Then the answer is the same as my question, `window[function](arg1, arg2, arg3)`

Comment: @Asad i get the arguments in variable like  var firstArguments = 'b';

Comment: @ Jan Dvorak args1,args2,args3 are javascript variables?If they how can you call many different function with different no of arguments

Comment: I didn't get notified for your previous comment, sorry. I don't understand what you mean by it. If `args1`, `args2`, `args3` are discrete variables, you should know their count already. If they are members of an array, then you can use `function.apply(window, args)` to use `args` as the argument list.

Comment: @VinothKumar I think you should explain the larger problem you're trying to solve as what you're trying to do just sounds wrong to a lot of us

Comment: not only for one function it may be needed for many function with different no of arguments like.. function a(b),function c(d,e) function f(g,h,i) i have to call all function with that i can get the number of arguments with array.but how can i call function with arguments

Comment: @Jan Dvorak any comments? i tried function.apply(window,args). It not worked.any more way to call function dynamically with argument array

Comment: If you want to call several functions in turn, go ahead. Where's the problem with that?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak i pass arguments as array but window[funcName](arg1,arg2) and funcName.apply(window.args) not worked with argument array so any other way to call dynamically function with argument array.

Comment: `window[funcName].apply(window, args)`, not `window[funcName].apply(window.args)`. The first argument to `Function#apply` is the `this` object, the second argument is the argument list.

Comment: @ Jan Dvorak hi that's great! It worked.    **window[funcName].apply(window, args)**  It is the one am looking for thanks for your effort.thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's much more simplier then you think

```
var f = function (a, b, c) {...};

var a = ...,
    b = ...,
    c = ...;
//to call a function do
f(a,b,c); 
//or
f.call(null, a, b, c);
//or
f.apply(null, [a,b,c]);
```

Comment: i am getting a,b,c as array then how can i use this

Comment: Do you know any way to pass arguments array?  f.apply(null, [a,b,c]) not worked f is the functionName for me then how can i use f.apply(null,[a,b,c])

Comment: It worked while i try like    <b>window[funcName].apply(window, args) </b> anyhow thanks.

Comment: @VinothKumar,I suggest looking [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)